# Webpack - HMR Plugin throws error on npm run build/dev

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

For building up a new project, Im using `webpack 4.29.6` and `webpack-dev-server 3.2.1` Now on my config file. I want to add the             `HotModuleReplacementPlugin()`, but it throws me an error when I execute either npm run build or npm run dev.

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.plugins[3] should be one of these:
   object { apply, … } | function
   -> Plugin of type object or instanceof Function
   Details:
    * configuration.plugins[3] should be an object.
      -> Plugin instance
    * configuration.plugins[3] should be an instance of function
      -> Function acting as plugin
```

Can anyone help me out on this? Take note that the plugin is only applied if the mode is production.

```
 plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
            Object.assign({}, {
                    inject: true,
                    template: publicDir + '/index.html',
                },
                isProduction ? {
                    minify: {
                        removeComments: true,
                        collapseWhitespace: true,
                        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                        useShortDoctype: true,
                        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                        keepClosingSlash: true,
                        minifyJS: true,
                        minifyCSS: true,
                        minifyURLs: true,
                    },
                } : undefined)),
        isProduction &&
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
            chunkFilename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
        }),
        isDevelopment && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If `isProduction` or `isDevelopment` is not true you pass their value as a plugin.

You can try something like this:

```
const PLUGINS = [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign({}, {
                inject: true,
                template: publicDir + '/index.html',
            },
            isProduction ? {
                minify: {
                    removeComments: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                    keepClosingSlash: true,
                    minifyJS: true,
                    minifyCSS: true,
                    minifyURLs: true,
                },
            } : undefined
        )
    ),
];

if (isProduction) PLUGINS.push(
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
        chunkFilename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
    })
);

if (isDevelopment) PLUGINS.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
);

....

plugins: PLUGINS,
```

Comment: your approach is valid and helps me out! thanks!! But what I dont understand why it does work with the default create-react-app configuration and on my part it doesnt...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the advice of @UjinT34 if the conditions on my plugins are false, I suddenly dont add a plugin in the array but a boolean value. Thats why at the end of plugins array I just needed to filter out the booleans, like that:

```
plugins: [
       ...
        isDevelopment && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ].filter(Boolean),
...
```